# In mako, how can I cycle through a list and display each value?

Tags: python, templates, pylons, mako

I have a Python list that I'm supplying to the template:

```
{'error_name':'Please enter a name',
 'error_email':'Please enter an email'}
```

And would like to display:

```
<ul>
<li>Please enter a name</li>
<li>Please enter an email</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's not a list, that's a dict.

Comment: What code did you try?  Please post the template you tried that doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<ul>
% for prompt in whateveryoucalledit.values():
  <li>${prompt}</li>
% endfor
</ul>
```

where `whateveryoucalledit` it is the name under which you chose to pass that container (which, as a comment noticed, is a dict, not a list).  The nice thing about mako, after all, is precisely that it's wonderfully close to Python itself (except for the need to "strop" things around a bit, and explicitly close blocks rather than just indend/deindent;-).